# jquery get api using jquery get

Tags: jquery, jsonp, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing a simple test using the [wakoopa (software tracking) api](http://social.wakoopa.com/api). Typing the following url in a browser relusts in unformated json

http://social.wakoopa.com/makingthings/software.json?

According to wakoopa "By default JSON-responses are wrapped in a callback function named `wakoopaApi`" I'm trying to so a simple jquery test: with no reults

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.get("http://social.wakoopa.com/makingthings/software.json?sort=active_seconds&period=month", function wakoopaApi(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data.software);
  });
});
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.getJSON("http://social.wakoopa.com/makingthings/software.json?sort=active_seconds&period=month&callback=?", function(data){
       $.each(data, function(){
           alert(this.software.name);    
        });
     });
});
```

in this way you add a parameter that specifies the callback (`callback=?`) and everything works

Look here http://jsfiddle.net/ZSzrm/